# How to customize NGINX after installation?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, installation, configure

I have installed **NGINX** (nginx-1.9.3.tar.gz format file downloaded from official website) everything is right, but now i want to turn it on, but i can't.

> I read many articles about this but every one says different thing and
>   none of them works for me.

Can anyone tell me how to make service to start or restart NGINX with

*service nginx start (or restart...)*

And also start NGINX automatically when computer will boot up.

Shortly I need to know what to do after installation. (I am using Ubuntu 14.04)

*Thanks for your attention.*

Comment: Why did you install from source instead of using official ubuntu-package?

Comment: @uzsolt i want to install newest version and plus make some changes (to turn on/off some modules).

Comment: Oh, understand. I think you should borrow initscript from official ubuntu package and maybe make some modifications on it.